# Why CSS works with "python manage.py runserver" but not with Gunicorn?

Tags: django

When I run, from the command line,

```
python manage.py runserver mywebsite.com:8099
```

the css works fine. But when I use the systemd service with Gunicorn socket, the app works but without the css. Even if I use the following command: gunicorn demo.wsgi:application, the app works fine but without the css.

Excerpt from my settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = "static/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "mystaticfiles"
]
```

Excerpt from my nginx config file:

```
    location /static/ {
        root /root/djdeploy/demo/static;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
```

My Django project working directory is: /root/djdeploy/demo/,

I have put my css files in the following folder: /root/djdeploy/demo/mystaticfiles

Comment: Did you do `python manage.py collectstatic` on your server? What does the network tab show when you load the page?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Is it the same as STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "mystaticfiles"
]. If so should I do : STATIC_ROOT = "/root/djdeploy/demo/mystaticfiles"
 ?

Comment: I think `STATICFILES_DIRS` is only for development purposes. For deployment, you need to set `STATIC_ROOT` and run `python manage.py collectstatic` on your server. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/#deployment for more details.

Comment: According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files, `STATICFILES_DIRS` tells Django where to find static files. This works with `python manage.py runserver` and `python manage.py collectstatic`, but it doesn't tell nginx where to find the files on a production server.

Answer (score 1):

1. There was a hidden problem of permission. I put the static folder in /var/www/ instead of the root folder. Then I changed ownership to allow nginx to get access to it:

   ```
   chown -R root:www-data /var/www/static/
   ```
2. in nginx configuration the word static shouldn't be repeated. That is to do this:

   ```
   location /static/ {
       root /var/www/;
   }
   ```

   instead of this:

   ```
   location /static/ {
       root /var/www/static;
   }
   ```
3. I changed the STATIC_ROOT VARIABLE in setting.py as follows:

   ```
   STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/static"
   ```

Then I restarted nginx and gunicorn service and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS works when you do `python manage.py runserver` because it knows where to find static files in your code. On the other hand, gunicorn doesn't know where to look for them.

You need to set `STATIC_ROOT` and run `python manage.py collectstatic` on your server. You already have nginx set up to serve the files once you collect them to the location that nginx will look for them.

See [the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/#deployment) for more details about deploying. Also see [the section on configuring static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files).

Comment: I did: python manage.py collectstatic. Now all the css files are in the static folder. But the problem is not solved. When I run Gunicorn I get the error: Not Found: /css/style.css, Not Found: /static/style.css .. etc

Comment: I added first STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') to my settings.py
. Then I did: python manage.py collectstatic. The problem persists

Comment: @Nadirspam It looks like you figured this out. The key is that `STATIC_ROOT` needs to be a folder that nginx can access. This usually means it is outside of your python project folder.